# tutorial of run-time hacking with Dnspy

Tags: patching

Is anybody have good resource or tutorial of run-time hacking or memory hacking with .NET Applications with dnspy.

Comment: it's a bit broad topic. Can you post a specific question/problem that you have?

Comment: I want to edit loaded c++ dll in c# environment with dnspy i must edit ram on runtime.